# Instantiating Null Objects with Null-Coalescing Operator

Tags: c#, operators

Consider the following typical scenario:

```
if(myObject == null) {
    myObject = new myClass();
}
```

I'm wondering what is thought of the following replacement using the null-coalescing operator:

```
myObject = myObject ?? new myClass();
```

I'm not sure whether I should be using the second form. It seems like a nice shorthand, but the `myObject = myObject` construct at the beginning seems like it could be a bit of a code-smell.

Is this a reasonable thing to do, or is there a better shorthand that I am missing?  Or maybe, "It's three lines, get over it!"?

Edit:
As has been mentioned, perhaps calling this a typical scenario is something of an overstatement. I usually find that I encounter this situation when I'm retrieving an entity from a database that has a child reference type property that may or may not be populated yet:

```
myClass myObject = myClassService.getById(id);
myObject.myChildObject = myObject.myChildObject ?? new myChildClass();
```

Comment: Newbies believe things like this to be "hackish", more experienced devs just call it "idiomatic".

Comment: If the object looks like a value object ("has value semantics", in idiomatic speak), `MyClass` should provide a `public static readonly` member of a `Empty` value of its type. See [`String.Empty` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.empty.aspx).

Comment: http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/02/portrait-of-n00b.html

Comment: Isn't there a `??=` operator?

Comment: @aviv (I'm not a C# guy at all) I don't see one in [this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

Comment: Some extension methods have a `ThisOrEmpty<T>` which requires less typing.

Comment: FWIW in the JavaScript world you'll see a lot of their null-coalescing operator for optional parameter default values. Like such: `props = props || {};` (`props` is a method param that we set to an empty obj if its not passed in).

Comment: **less is more**

Comment: @aviv I wish there was!

Answer (score 16):

I use the null coalescing operator all of the time.  I like the conciseness of it.

I find this operator to be similar in nature to the ternary operator (A ? B : C).  It takes a little practice before the reading of it is second nature, but once you're used to it I feel readability improves over the longhand versions.

Also, the situation you describe is only one scenario where the operator is useful.  It's also handy to replace constructs like this:

```
if (value != null)
{
    return value;
}
else
{ 
    return otherValue;
}
```

or

```
return value != null ? value : otherValue;
```

with

```
return value ?? otherValue;
```

Comment: Definitely agree in general about using this operator. When I see references to using it, though, it's typically something like `myObject = myObject2 ?? myObject3`.  What I'm wondering about specifically is using the operator to set an object to itself unless it's null.

Comment: I think the same reasoning applies in either case.  It's a more concise way to express the same logic.

Comment: I remember looking at the IL for each of those three forms once. The first and the second were identical, but the third was optimized in a fashion as it could assume `null` was a comparison.

Answer (score 2):

> What I'm wondering about specifically is using the operator to set an object to itself unless it's null.

The `?? operator` is called the null-coalescing operator and is used to define a default value for nullable value types or reference types. It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the right operand.

`myObject = myObject ?? new myObject();` - `instantiate default value of object`

More details and code sample about null-coalescing operator - [**MSDN article**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

If you check for `more than nullable` condition, as an **alternative** you may use Ternary operator.

## Ternary operator

You may also look at **?: Operator**. It is called **Ternary or conditional** operator. The conditional operator (?:) returns one of two values depending on the value of a Boolean expression.

> A nullable type can contain a value, or it can be undefined. The ?? operator defines the default value to be returned when a nullable type is assigned to a non-nullable type. If you try to assign a nullable value type to a non-nullable value type without using the ?? operator, you will generate a compile-time error. If you use a cast, and the nullable value type is currently undefined, an InvalidOperationException exception will be thrown.

A code example from [MSDN - ?: Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

```
int? input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
string classify;

// ?: conditional operator.
classify = (input.HasValue) ? ((input < 0) ? "negative" : "positive") : "undefined";
```

Comment: So taking the example from the question and applying the conditional operator, we'd have something like `myObject = (myObject == null) ? new myClass() : myObject`.  So, unless I'm missing a better usage of the conditional operator, it seems to have the same "problem" with setting an object to itself (if it's not null) as the null-coalescing operator--and it's less concise.

Comment: If you are checking for more than one condition (Not null and greater than zero) - then conditional operator will do it. However, just null checking would work for ?? operator.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that scenario is (or at least should be) typical.

If you want the default value of some field not to be `null`, then set it in the field initializer:

```
myClass myObject = new myClass();
```

Or, if the initialization is more complicated, set it in the constructor.

If you want to create `myClass` only when you actually need it (e.g. because creating it takes a long time), then you can use [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx):

```
Lazy<myClass> myObject = new Lazy<myClass>();
```

(This calls the default constructor. If the initialization is more complicated, pass lambda that creates `myClass` to the `Lazy<T>` constructor.)

To access the value, use `myObject.Value`, which will call the initialization if this is the first time you're accessing `myObject.Value`.

Comment: IMO lazy creation is only useful if you are not guaranteed to need the resulting object, only time I use lazy creation is when I have a cashed derived result that I reset when something changes and I know that I'll need the same result a lot and the recalc is expensive. other wise I just don't want to bother with the null check

Comment: @ratchetfreak Yes, that's why I suggested field initializer first.

Comment: There are other cases also.  What I'm looking at at the moment:  The first pass sets the exception cases.  The second pass sets defaults for everything else.  ??= would cut the line in half.

Answer (score 1):

I especially like using `??` in conjunction with optional method parameters. I limit the need for overloads and ensure the thing has a value.

```
public void DoSomething (MyClass thing1 = null) {
    thing1 = thing1 ?? new MyClass();
}
```